# glob() — Sort by Name

Tags: php, sorting, foreach, reverse, glob

How can I reverse the sort by filename?  Currently it displays all the text files in alphabetical / numerical order, but I'm trying to have it display in descending order instead.  Right now, I have...

```
<?php  
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
   include($filename);
}
?>
```

I'm pretty new to PHP, but I tried usort with array added on but that just resulted in it displaying only 1 of the text files, so either that doesn't work or I just coded it wrong.

Comment: The reverse sort function would be `rsort()` but needs to a be separate statement with a temporary array variable.

Comment: I ran into some perceived alphabetic sorting problem but the underlying issue is that lowercased letters have higher ascii values than uppercased. A filename like myphoto1.jpg is returned after myPhoto2.jpg because of the capital P.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `array_reverse`:

```
foreach(array_reverse(glob("*.txt")) as $filename) { ...
```

Answer (score 17):

Just a addition to @Foo Bah's answer :
When dealing with file names in a directory, I usually add `natsort` to prevent the typical ordering case :

> - 'image1.png'
> - 'image10.png'
> - 'image2.png'

[natsort](https://php.net/manual/fr/function.natsort.php) is a more user friendly sorting algorithm that will preserve natural numbering :

> - 'image1.png'
> - 'image2.png'
> - 'image10.png'

So FooBah's answer becomes :

```
$list = glob("*.jpg");
natsort($list);
foreach(array_reverse($list) as $filename) { ...
```

Please note that `natsort` is modifying the array passed in parameter and only returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

For optimal performance, I would suggest to **avoid unnecessary array processing** (i.e. sorting or reversing) when dealing with **large arrays**.

Since the [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function sorts the filenames in ascending order as default behaviour, you can simply loop through the resulting array in reverse order, and therefore avoid any other processing:

```php
<?php
for($result = glob("*.txt"), $i = count($result); $i > 0; --$i) {
    include($result[$i-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it with `usort()` would be...

```
usort($files, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($b, $a);
});
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IIkGkV).